# Android Studio: Can't switch to new activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-activity

I'm trying to learn Android development and have gone through the basic tutorials.  I'm making a golf scorecard application.  Originally I went from Homescreen -> SelectCourseActivity -> Scorecard.  Everything was working fine, but I wanted to get rid of the SelectCourseActivity, so I tried to have the main button on the Homescreen to straight to the Scorecard, but now it always throws this exception:

```
catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not execute method for android:onClick", e);
        }
```

Here is the code for the button OnClick:

```
public void Scorecard(View view)  {
    Intent MyIntent = new Intent(this, ScorecardActivity.class);
    startActivity(MyIntent);
}
```

And yes I have gone into the AndroidManifest and set the parent of ScorecardActivity to Homescreen.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/wgcc_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/wgcc_icon_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".HomeScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectCourseActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ScorecardActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>

</application>
```

Even after I returned everything to normal using Git, the ScorecardActivity will still not start.  I appreciate any and all help! Please let me know if there's any more information needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve the problem, but try add `Homescreen.this` instead of just `this` in this line `Intent MyIntent = new Intent(this, ScorecardActivity.class);`

Comment: why is there a spinner in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a dumb mistake, that I just figured out.  I'm storing the information necessary for the scorecard on a local file, because originally I wanted to learn how that worked for android studio.  Turns out that I wasn't asking permission to access the devices local files before I tried to load the scorecard information in the ScorecardActivity OnCreate.  As a follow up, anybody know how to ensure that permission is obtained before the information is accessed?

Comment: This [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files) may help you with file permissions

Answer (score 1):

If what @DmytroSytro doesn't work, you can try editing your manifest file to look like the below and see if that helps you.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/wgcc_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/wgcc_icon_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".HomeScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ScorecardActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeScreen">
        <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
               android:value="com.example.android.your_activity_class.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in OnCreate:

```
 Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Homescreen.this, Scorecard.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```